# Need better regex solution in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have following code:

```
date_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
name = "builder-#{date_time}"   # builder-20150923125450

if some_condition
  name.sub!("#{date_time}", "one-#{date_time}") # builder-one-20150923125450
end
```

Above code is working fine.
But I think it could be better as I feel like I am repeating `#{date_time}` twice here.

I have heard of regex `capture and replace`. Can we use it here? If yes, how?

Comment: You mean you cannot change the code that creates the string `name`, and you have to modify it?

Comment: Why don't you like this solution (in question)?

Comment: I will update with full code.

Comment: I think you should not have used the term *optimize* here, as what you ask for is just help with some basic regex notion of capture groups. I do not know if it "optimizes" your code, but definitely gives you more control over the substring replacements (if you have some specific pattern).

Comment: An array could help: `['builder', ('one' if cond), date_time].compact.join('-')`

Comment: @Stefan I would do: `['builder', *('one' if cond), date_time].join('-')`.

Comment: @sawa excellent use of `*`!

Comment: ...or `"builder-%s%s" % [*('one-' if cond), date_time]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To utilize capturing mechanism, you need to use *round brackets* round a subpattern that you would like to refer to using a back-reference in the replacement string.

Here is an example:

```
date_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
name = "builder-#{date_time}"
puts name.sub(/^([^-]*-)/, "\\1one-")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/DvlXPV)

The `^([^-]*-)` matches and captures all characters other than `-` from the beginning of the string (`^`) and a hyphen, and then we refer to the text with `\\1` in the replacement string.

Refer to [*Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing* at Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for more details.

A more optimal way is using a ternary operator when initializing `name` variable:

```
a = 1
date_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
name = "builder-" + (some_condition ? "one-" : "") + "#{date_time}"
```

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iVnPDe)

Comment: @Downvoter: Any hint on what is wrong? *I have heard of regex capture and replace. Can we use it here? If yes, how?* - I guess my answer addresses that.

Comment: Accepting for this solution "name.sub(/^([^-]*-)/, "\\1one-")" as one is also variable here and need to be interpolated at some time. Please remove other optimal way to be precise with solution.

Comment: How can anything be "more optimal" than something else? "Better", yes.

Comment: Thanks  anyway. I have less grip on regex :)

Comment: @ram: I added that ternary operator option for the downvoters. I think they did it because I suggested the regex.

Comment: How is a newline character relevant to this question?

Comment: @sawa: Could you clarify what newline character you mean? I have not mentioned any in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Strategy one - precalculate the prefix:

```
date_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
prefix    = some_condition ? 'builder-one-' : 'builder-'
name      = "#{prefix}#{date_time}"
```

The string `'builder-'` is repeated twice here. Obviously, you can DRY it even more, but it's an overkill IMHO.

---

Strategy two - use a lookahead:

```
date_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
name      = "builder-#{date_time}"

name.sub!(/(?=#{date_time})/, "one-") if some_condition
```

Now `date_time` appears only twice. I wouldn't say it's a great improvement. I wouldn't say there is much of a problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
"builder-" + ("one-" if some_condition).to_s + date_time

date_time = "right now"

some_condition = true
"builder-" + ("one-" if some_condition).to_s + date_time
  #=> "builder-one-right now"

some_condition = false
"builder-" + ("one-" if some_condition).to_s + date_time
 #=> "builder-right now"
```

Note that:

```
("one-" if false).to_s #=> nil.to_s => ""
```